# regedx working on a gloabl scale where 2 or more results shoud return

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find certain results (could be more than 1) and then process these, having issues with the /g. doesnt seem to want to return multiple results

I have the following code

```
<div id="test"> 
<p> <!--{Byond:cta|localAction:contact|Contact Us}--><\/p> 
<p> &nbsp;<\/p> <p> <sub><strong>Important Information:<\/strong>&nbsp;Offer 
only available for new home loans. *Comparison Rate is calculated on a loan amount of 
$150,000 over a term of 25 years. **Minimum redraw of $500. ^Limits apply for fixed rate 
home loans.<\/sub><\/p> <!--{Byond:cta|localAction:product:45|Product}--> 
</div>
```

I am trying to get each instance of the byond local action amd then split the string

I am using

```
var introduction = $("#test").html();
var initExpr = /<!--{Byond\:cta\|localAction[^}]+}-->/gm;
var initResult = initExpr.exec(introduction);


    // this result is always 1... WHY?
    var length = initResult.length;

    //based on the length split the results up

 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 var expr = /(?:<!--{Byond\:cta\|)(.*)\|(.*)(?:}-->)/i;
 var result = expr.exec(introduction);
 console.log(result[0], "String");
 console.log(result[1], "Local Action");
 console.log(result[2], "Button Name");


}
```

I only ever get length of 1 for the first result.. should be 2.. and then need to use that to work out splitting individual result

Can anyone help

Comment: You must escape the curly brackets when they are outside a character class. `:` don't need to be escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the matches, you must put the exec() method in a while loop.

You can have the result your are looking for with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var subject = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
    var pattern = /<!--\{Byond:cta\|([^|]+)\|([^|}]+)\}-->/g;
    var result = new Array();
    while( (match = pattern.exec(subject)) != null ) {
        result.push(match);
    }
</script>
```

You obtain:

```
[["<!--{Byond:cta|localAction:contact|Contact Us}-->",
  "localAction:contact",
  "Contact Us"], 
 ["<!--{Byond:cta|localAction:product:45|Product}-->",
  "localAction:product:45",
  "Product"]]
```